# What is the Best Practice for testing api controllers(active model serializers)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, active-model-serializers

I am working on an app and up to this point I have been testing just stuff like authentication and request response codes. but it seems like a good idea to test the structure of the payload. ie. if there is embedded resources or sidloaded resources. how do you guys test this. here is a sample of some of the testing I am doing. I am using active model serializers. but seems like a bit of cruft to organize.

```
describe '#index' do
  it 'should return an array of email templates' do
    template = EmailTemplate.new(name: 'new email template')
    EmailTemplate.stub(:all).and_return([template])
    get :index
    payload = {:email_templates => [JSON.parse(response.body)["email_templates"][0].symbolize_keys]}
    template_as_json_payload = {:email_templates => [ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(template).as_json[:email_template] ]}
    expect(payload).to eq(template_as_json_payload)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fond of defining a schema for JSON responses and validating that any response seen in a test conforms to it. That alone does not guarantee that the values of the response are correct but it does tell you that the structure of the response matched your expectations.

Those schemas then become part of the documentation of the API which client implementations can reference. By using the schema in tests I get more confidence that the API documentation is not going to fall out of sync with the implementation. Making schema changes in order to get a passing test is also a good prompt for me to consider if a change is safe for existing API clients or if I need to release a new API version.

The folks at Thoughtbot have a nice example of validating schemas using rspec: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/validating-json-schemas-with-an-rspec-matcher

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
body = JSON.parse(response.body)
assert_equal(body.keys, ["id", "author"])
assert_equal(body["author"].keys, ["id", "name"])
```

But you should checkout the link that **Jonah** shared, it's worth reading.